# Ruby renaming file in directory deletes files

Tags: ruby

I have this code that does some renaming of images in the current directory:

```
puts Dir["**/*"].length

folder_path = Dir.pwd

filenames = Dir.glob("*.png")

filenames.each_with_index do |filename, index|
  File.rename(filename, folder_path + "/#{index}" + File.extname(filename))
end
```

My console:

```
98
$ ruby rename.rb
90
$ ruby rename.rb
90
$ ruby rename.rb
90
$ ruby rename.rb
82
$ ruby rename.rb
82
$ ruby rename.rb
74
$ ruby rename.rb
74
$ ruby rename.rb
66
```

It seems like the 3th time I run the code some images are deleted in the progress.

Comment: Unrelated, but `#{index.to_s}` is redundant. Using `#{}` invokes `to_s` already, so you're effectively doing `index.to_s.to_s`. Just use `#{index}`.

Comment: @meagar updated. If I update the script every I run it with a new filename example "/sa#{index}" the files are not deleted.

Comment: "It seems like the 3th time I run the code some images are deleted in the progress." -- Are they deleted?  You say it seems like it.  I can run this code over and over and all it does it name the PNG's 0.png, 1.png, 2.png etc.  Seems fine.

Comment: @NickVeys they are deleted the 3th time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way your script can erase files is by erasing existing file with the same name... You can check if a file already exists like that:

```
puts Dir["**/*"].length

folder_path = Dir.pwd

filenames = Dir.glob("*.png")

filenames.each_with_index do |filename, index|
  new_name= folder_path + "/#{index}" + File.extname(filename)
  raise "#{new_name} already exists" if File.exists?(new_name)
  File.rename(filename, new_name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want rename the file even when the file with the name exist:

```
folder_path = Dir.pwd
filenames = Dir.glob('*.png')

filenames.each_with_index do |filename, index|
  new_name = folder_path + "/#{index}" + File.extname(filename)
  unless File.exists?(new_name)
       File.rename(filename, new_name)
  else
      index += 1
      new_name = folder_path + "/#{index}" + File.extname(filename)
      File.rename(filename, new_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Since there is no check before the second rename, this script can still override files.